# Who is the manufacturer of this LED array?

Tags: identification, led-matrix

This is from a Cat6 tracer.  It's an LED array and 3 of them have died.

I am looking to identify first who the manufacturer is and then who might be selling it.

When I google it, there are too many parts of the same number, but are totally different.

The part number looks like **BA-2E8G1UD**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manufacturer is [Bright LED Electronics Corp.](https://www.brtled.com/web/company/company.jsp?lang=en&no=0) As you can see, the logo matches.

[image]

Since there are a very large number of possible combinations of LED colors and LED position you may not find such a mixed-color bar-graph easily available (or it might be easily available).

I believe the part number specifies 2 red bar segments (high **E**fficiency red) and 8 **G**reen segments.

There are many manufacturers of similar products, and if you meet their minimum order quantity some (perhaps not the best ones) will assemble whatever colors you want in whatever order you want (maybe a couple thousand dollar order).

If color doesn't matter so much to you, you can almost surely substitute a similar device with all one color of segments. They are inexpensive (even for one or two at a time) and are available from many distributors. Just look for 10-segment 'bar graph' displays.